# Price discrimination question

Tags: microeconomics, monopoly, price-discrimination

[image]

For this question the answer is b which is the TR of group 2. If price is the same, my question is why isn't the demand function of group 1 considered? Why is the TR of group 1 omitted?

Answer (score 2):

To sell 45 units to group 2 implies a price of $220-2Q_2=130$. At that price, demand from group 1 is zero. Indeed, the very most any consumer in group 1 is willing to pay is $100$.

Comment: I see. So we have to first deduce the willing to pay price and then work out TR after? Thanks

Comment: Please could I have some hints on this question also? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/29444/production-function-involving-profit-maximisation         I would really appreciate it as it is hard to get help from my teachers. Thanks.