# Production function involving profit maximisation

Tags: microeconomics, production-function, profit-maximization, marginal, cost-functions

​Hi, I don't get how the answer of d is deduced in this question because I don't think I made any mistakes in my calculation and have also used all the information given. After knowing L is 800, I found out the did 200*Q which gives me 5656 and I worked out the profit to be negative but it is not -15000. What did I do wrong in my calculation?
[image]
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max [image]

Then you have: Max [image: 200*L^(0.5) - 10*L - 16000]

Which gives you: [image]

So L = 100, and you have a loss of 15000

Comment: He is right. The problem with your calculations is that you want to use MPl/MPk= w/v whenever you are finding both K and L (typically considered the Long run solution) Here since you already have K fixed (often considered the short run problem), you want to equate the value of the marginal productivity of labor to the wage: P*MPl=w. This is exactly his third equation. Notice how in the problem before taking derivatives he plugged in the value of K

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is helpful.

Comment: Sorry, in the first equation it's 16*K.